# Finding a Date in a Excell Sheet when the date is a formula

Tags: vba

I have a field in an Excel sheet named **DateFromTo**. I need to find the row number based on this date, but the sheet cells are date formatted and just a copy of the first cell + 1 day (=A3867+1). How can I do this with the **.Find**

```
Set FindRow = Sheets("DateFromTo").Range("A:A").Find(What:=ReportDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Comment: What error are you getting, or what is this doing in error?  It works for me.

Comment: I'm getting nothing. I set the results to a field in another sheet and it doesn't show the results. When I step through it, it says that FindRow = Nothing.      Sheets("tb-final").Activate
    Range("A21") = FindRow.Row